# Reinitialize variable in jquery after ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
$selectsPersons = $('select.persons');

// when user adds a select
$('#button-add-select').on('click', function (e) {
    $('#container-selects').append('<select class="persons"><option value="" selected="" disabled="disabled" data-placeholder="Fach">Fach</option><option value="1">Person 1</option><option value="2">Person 2</option><option value="3">Person 3</option></select>');
});

// when user changes persons in a select
$('body').on('change', 'select.persons', function () {
    $selectsPersons.find('option').prop('disabled', false);

    $selectsPersons.each(function () {
        $selectsPersons.not(this).find('option[value="' + this.value + '"]').prop('disabled', true);
    });

    $selectsPersons.selectmenu('refresh', true);
});
```

The user can add multiple selects in a div. When the user changes the person in a select menu, already selected persons in other select menus will be displayed as disabled.

How can I achieve that in the 'change persons' function, my variable `$selectsPerson` will cover ***all* selects that in the moment of changing persons have been added so far**? Of course I could simply replace $selectsPerson with $('select.persons'), but my goal is to be able to simply use the variable I declared at the beginning of the script, $selectsPerson.

Answer (score 0):

Simply override it after appending the new select element.

```
var $selectsPersons = $('select.persons');

// when user adds a select
$('#button-add-select').on('click', function (e) {
    $('#container-selects').append('<select class="persons"><option value="" selected="" disabled="disabled" data-placeholder="Fach">Fach</option><option value="1">Person 1</option><option value="2">Person 2</option><option value="3">Person 3</option></select>');
    $selectsPersons = $('select.persons');
});

// when user changes persons in a select
$('body').on('change', 'select.persons', function () {
    $selectsPersons.find('option').prop('disabled', false);

    $selectsPersons.each(function () {
        $selectsPersons.not(this).find('option[value="' + this.value + '"]').prop('disabled', true);
    });

    $selectsPersons.selectmenu('refresh', true);
});
```

(note I added the `var` keyword. If you don't add the `var` keyword before variable name, it will become a global)